# How does text in a file opened with text editor move right when charecter is typed at random position?

Tags: c, file-io

The same thing does not happen when text is written to a file using c library functions. What should I do so that when I write to a particular location in a file all the text on the right is arranged automatically just like text editor.
Just to add to the question I work on linux os, but is there some facility that is independent of operating system, some thing like the support of standard library or is there any programming construct to implement this?

Comment: There is no magic way to insert a character in the middle of a text file. You'll need to read and remember the rest of the file, write the newly inserted character, then write the chunk you saved at step 1 after it.

Comment: Text files are usually fairly small, compared to the memory available on modern computers. So the text editor can keep the file in memory as a linked list of lines. Inserting a character simply updates one of the lines. If you're working with a file that doesn't fit into memory, then things get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you dxiv. So, is this the way .txt and word documents .doc work to implement the above

Comment: .doc files are more complicated.

Comment: @charanchakravarhy No text editor that I know of would resave the file each time a `character is typed at random position`. Rather, you'd cache (parts of) the file in memory as @user3386109 hinted, and only save to disk when necessary. For complex formats like word .doc files it's even more complicated, since the text stream is interspersed with formatting info, and sometimes even the history of changes.

Comment: Thanks all. But generally speaking is this the idea (said by dxiv) followed by most popular text editors?

Comment: I really wouldn't call Word a "text editor". It has so many more features than that, and its `.doc`/`.docx` files contain *way* more than just text.

Answer (score 0):

I see we have an intermixture of answers here, each incorrect to varying degrees.  A text editor works upon a copy of the subject file, not upon the file itself.  This copy is maintained in memory to the extent possible, while portions are written to one or more scratch files as necessary.  When you insert a character into a line in visual or "open" mode, those manipulations are being done upon an in-memory copy of the text.  The editor itself redraws the viewable text portion as it sees fit, taking advantage of "cursor control" by any number of techniques.  Libraries such as curses and termcap all avail themselves, at the lowest level, of various escape codes that are understood by the "upper half" of the TTY driver.  (Pardon my UNIX bias: the Windows analogues are--as is ALWAYS the case--either [1] in flux, [2] poorly understood/documented, or [3] "secret") The file is reassembled as a unified byte string and written to disk when you issue a "save" command to the text editor.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, could you please suggest me some material or some good reads to elaborate on your answer.

Comment: The WinAPI is pretty well documented and has been for years, and as with everything on Windows, there's probably a 3rd party library that makes things easier for you anyway. Take that "UNIX bias" out of your answer, and i'll give you my +1 (p.s. I use both unix and windows on a daily basis)

Comment: `Pardon my UNIX bias` Pardon my Windows bias ;-) but there is no rule set in stone that a text editor *has* to be TTY. As it happens, my daily text editor in Windows (of emacs inspiration) comes in both GUI and console flavors. It has served me well for the past 20+ years, using the not-so-secret Windows APIs.